# How do I input variables to change label text using javascript

Tags: javascript, text, label, inputbox

I am trying to make it so that when the user inputs a names into the inputbox and then clicks the 'Enter Candidates' button, it will then change the name of the labels below. Is there a way to do this in javascript? i have just started coding so i am a bit of a newbie.

```
            <form class="simple-form">
                <div>Enter your candidate <b>names</b> in the boxes below:</div>
                <br/>
                <label for="C1">Candidate 1:</label>
                <input type="text" name="C1" id="C1" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="C2">Candidate 2:</label>
                <input type="text" name="C2" id="C2" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="C3">Candidate 3:</label>
                <input type="text" name="C3" id="C3" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="C4">Candidate 4:</label>
                <input type="text" name="C4" id="C4" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="C5">Candidate 5:</label>
                <input type="text" name="C5" id="C5" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <input type="button" OnClick="EnterCandidates" value="Enter Candidates" />
                <br/>

                <br/>
                <div>Enter the candidates <b>votes</b> in the boxes below:</div>
                <br/>
                <label for="V1" id="L_V1">Name 1:</label>
                <input type="text" name="V1" id="I_V1" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="V2" id="L_V2">Name 2:</label>
                <input type="text" name="V2" id="I_V2" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="V3" id="L_V3">Name 3:</label>
                <input type="text" name="V3" id="I_V3" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="V4" id="L_V4">Name 4:</label>
                <input type="text" name="V4" id="I_V4" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <label for="V5" id="L_V5">Name 5:</label>
                <input type="text" name="V5" id="I_V5" class="InputBox" />
                <br/>
                <input type="button" OnClick="" value="Enter Votes" />
                <br/>
            </form>
```

Thanks everyone who helped me. 
One more question.
I have decided to use this code (thanks @David Thomas):

```
function EnterCandidates() {
  var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
    names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function(label, index) {
    if (candidateNameInputs[index].value !== candidateNameInputs[index].defaultValue) {
      label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
    }
  });
}
```

How do i add a verification so that the user can only use string and it has a certain character limit like 20 characters?
I tried to add one of your guys suggestions to it but i guess i did it wrong because it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use

```
document.getElementById('Label ID').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Input ID').value
```

Please see here : http://jsfiddle.net/jzqp70oq/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make sure the user only inputs a string with a certain character limit?

Comment: Do you mean a length limit ? If yes, you can check it with `string.length`. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/jzqp70oq/2/

Comment: @erohs2000: if you need to add requirements to your question please edit the question; don't hide aspects that should inform all users in the comments to another answer. Help us (all) to help you, update the question (the 'edit' link is below the tags to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are expecting.

```
document.getElementById('L_V1').innerHTML= document.getElementById('C1').value;
```

//character validation

```
var val = document.getElementById('c2').value;

if (!val.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) 
{
    alert('Only alphabets are allowed');
    return false;
}
```

//Length validation

```
if (val.length >10) {
   alert("characters are too long !")
}
```

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/3pmamtec/)

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript achieves your desired output, I think:

```
function EnterCandidates() {

    // Using document.querySelectorAll() to get the <input> elements
    // whose id attribute/property starts with the upper-case letter C:
    var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),

    // finding the <label> elements whose 'for' attribute starts with
    // the upper-case letter V, and whose id starts with the string "L_V":
        names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]');

    // using Function.prototype.call() to iterate over the Array-like
    // nodeList, returned by document.querySelectorAll, using an
    // an Array method (Array.prototype.forEach()):
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function (label, index) {
        // the first argument of the anonymous function ('label')
        // is the array-element of the Array (or Array-like) structure
        // over which we're iterating, and is a <label> element,
        // the second argument ('index') is the index of that current
        // element in the Array (or Array-like structure).

        // if the value of the <input> at the same index in the collection
        // as the current <label>'s index has a value that is not
        // equal to its default-value:
        if (candidateNameInputs[index].value !== candidateNameInputs[index].defaultValue) {

            // we update the textcontent of the <label> to be
            // equal to that of the value entered in the <input>
            label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
        }
    });
}
```

```js
function EnterCandidates() {
  var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
    names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function(label, index) {
    if (candidateNameInputs[index].value !== candidateNameInputs[index].defaultValue) {
      label.textContent = candidateNameInputs[index].value;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
label::before {
  content: "\A";
 white-space: pre;
}
label::after {
  content: ': ';
}
label,
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
input[type=button]:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="simple-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter your candidate <b>names</b> in the boxes below:</legend>
    <label for="C1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="C1" id="C1" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="C2" id="C2" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="C3" id="C3" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C4">Candidate 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="C4" id="C4" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C5">Candidate 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="C5" id="C5" class="InputBox" />
    <input type="button" onclick="EnterCandidates()" value="Enter Candidates" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter the candidates <b>votes</b> in the boxes below:</legend>
    <label for="V1" id="L_V1">Name 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="V1" id="I_V1" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V2" id="L_V2">Name 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="V2" id="I_V2" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V3" id="L_V3">Name 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="V3" id="I_V3" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V4" id="L_V4">Name 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="V4" id="I_V4" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V5" id="L_V5">Name 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="V5" id="I_V5" class="InputBox" />
    <input type="button" value="Enter Votes" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39q3hosr/3), for experimentation and development.

Please note that I edited your HTML structure as well, to try and make it more semantic in its structure; removed the `<br>` nodes, and switched to CSS to to break the elements into new-lines; used the `<legend>` elements to hold the 'instructions' for each section (removing the `<div>` element you originally used). Also, I grouped the associated elements together using `<fieldset>` elements to wrap the `<label>` and `<input>` groups together, along with the relevant 'control' button.

Further, since it made it slightly easier to update the text without having to add back 'presentation' strings (the colons), I used CSS to achieve that end in order that presentation could be easily updated without using search/replace when – inevitably – the design changes.

With regard to the update to the question, and the question left in comments:

> is there a way to add a verification to this so that the user can only use letters of the alphabet. Also a character limit so that the user can only type <20 characters?And how do i implement it in this code? I will edit my post if there is an answer.

The answer, of course, is "yes," to do so I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function EnterCandidates() {
    var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
        names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]'),

        // A regular expression literal; which means:
        // the complete string, from the start (^)
        // to the end ($) must comprise of characters
        // a-z (inclusive), apostrophe (') and white-space
        // (to allow O'Neill, for example); this must be
        // zero to 20 characters in length ({0,20}) and
        // is case-insensitive (i):
        validity = /^[a-z'\s]{0,20}$/i,

        // two empty/uninitialised variables for use within
        // the forEach() loop:
        tempNode, tempVal;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function (label, index) {

        // caching the candidateNameInputs[index] Node:
        tempNode = candidateNameInputs[index];

        // caching the value of that Node:
        tempVal = tempNode.value;

        // if the value of the Node is not equal to the default-value
        // of the Node, AND the value of the Node matches the regular
        // expression (returns true if so, false if not):
        if (tempVal !== tempNode.defaultValue && validity.test(tempVal)) {

            // we remove the 'invalid' class from the Node if
            // it's present:
            tempNode.classList.remove('invalid');

            // update the text of the <label>:
            label.textContent = tempVal;

        // otherwise, if the value does not match (!) the
        // the regular expression:
        } else if (!validity.test(tempVal)) {

            // we add the 'invalid' class-name to the
            // Node:
            tempNode.classList.add('invalid');

            // and set the text of the <label> to
            // its original state, by concatenating
            // the string "Name " with the result of the
            // current (zero-based) index of the <label>
            // after adding 1 (to make it one-based):
            label.textContent = 'Name ' + (index + 1);

        // otherwise, if the value is equal to the default-value
        // we do nothing other than remove the 'invalid'
        // class-name from the <input> Node:
        } else if (tempVal === tempNode.defaultValue) {
            tempNode.classList.remove('invalid');
        }
    });
}
```

```js
function EnterCandidates() {
  var candidateNameInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=C]'),
    names = document.querySelectorAll('label[for^=V][id^=L_V]'),
    validity = /^[a-z'\s]{0,20}$/i,
    tempNode, tempVal;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, function(label, index) {
    tempNode = candidateNameInputs[index];
    tempVal = tempNode.value;

    if (tempVal !== tempNode.defaultValue && validity.test(tempVal)) {
      tempNode.classList.remove('invalid');
      label.textContent = tempVal;
    } else if (!validity.test(tempVal)) {
      tempNode.classList.add('invalid');
      label.textContent = 'Name ' + (index + 1);
    } else if (tempVal === tempNode.defaultValue) {
      tempNode.classList.remove('invalid');
    }

  });
}
```

```css
label::before {
  content: "\A";
 white-space: pre;
}
label::after {
  content: ': ';
}
label,
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}
input[type=button]:last-child {
  display: block;
}
input.invalid {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<form class="simple-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter your candidate <b>names</b> in the boxes below:</legend>
    <label for="C1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="C1" id="C1" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="C2" id="C2" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="C3" id="C3" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C4">Candidate 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="C4" id="C4" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="C5">Candidate 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="C5" id="C5" class="InputBox" />
    <input type="button" onclick="EnterCandidates()" value="Enter Candidates" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Enter the candidates <b>votes</b> in the boxes below:</legend>
    <label for="V1" id="L_V1">Name 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="V1" id="I_V1" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V2" id="L_V2">Name 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="V2" id="I_V2" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V3" id="L_V3">Name 3</label>
    <input type="text" name="V3" id="I_V3" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V4" id="L_V4">Name 4</label>
    <input type="text" name="V4" id="I_V4" class="InputBox" />
    <label for="V5" id="L_V5">Name 5</label>
    <input type="text" name="V5" id="I_V5" class="InputBox" />
    <input type="button" value="Enter Votes" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/39q3hosr/1/), for experimentation and development.

References:

- CSS:

  - [`::after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore).
  - [`::before` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore).
  - [`content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- HTML:

  - [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)
  - [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
  - [`<legend>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/legend).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLFieldSetElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement).
  - [`HTMLLabelElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement).
  - [`HTMLLegendElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLLegendElement).
  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: is there a way to add a verification to this so that the user can only use letters of the alphabet. Also a character limit so that the user can only type <20 characters?And how do i implement it in this code? I will edit my post if there is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){document.getElementById('Label_ID').innerHTML=document.getElementById('Input_ID').value;
}
</script>
</head>
//....
<input type="button" onClick="EnterCandidates();" value="Enter Candidates" />
//...
```